# Using RESTful API Calls to register a user

Tags: php, swift, api, rest, restful-architecture

When I want to register a user on my server, I use my RESTful API I created to do the job. So for example, I would make a `POST` request to  `http://server.com/users`

This API call will generate a new user id, if the user currently does not exist and save him to the database and then returns the newly created user id to the app, so the app knows about the user id being used from now on.

At the same time, I want to register the user's device as well to my web service, as I will send Push Notifications. Now this is not difficult in terms of how to do it, but I am thinking for a while now, how is it efficient? These are my thoughts:

- Using RESTful APIs means to me, that I use a clear way of separating tasks to different controllers. So I would have a `APIUserController` and a `APIDeviceController`. Therefore, if I want to register a user, it will be the `POST` request `http://server.com/users`, and to register a device it should be a `POST` request to `http://server.com/devices`. So the call to `users` would return the created `userID` and I would then make a `POST` request to `devices` with the `userID` I got returned by my first call. This means, two different calls from the app to the Server.
- But when I think about efficiency, my first thought would be, to make only one `POST` request to `http://server.com/users` containing all data needed (like the device token) and create the user on the server as well as creating the device. But this means, I would directly create the entry into the database, and mixing up responsibilities in the users controller.

I definitely need some help here on this. What is the purpose of differentiating the responsibilites when creating a new user AND registering a new device, when I then lose effiency by calling the server twice to use the restful approach?

Comment: I would associate users with various devices. Therefore, at the time of login  you need to detect the device and generate token for it. Having a new device should hardly matter as you should add that entry of device associated with the user and generate a token same as that you would do for a normal web based request. That should hardly differ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that arguably the devices *belong* to the users, so I don't see any harm in including the device information when you add a new user as an optional component. Sort of like if a user wants to optionally include their "bio". You probably wouldn't have a separate endpoint for "bios".

Also since you have a direct relationship between users and devices, perhaps it might be more logical instead of using a separate `/devices` endpoint to make it a sub directory of `/users`. Something like `/users/12345/devices`.

Comment: You may want to also check out http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/restfulresourcenaming.html

Comment: Well that is a valid point of view. But when I see "Parse.com" for example, they have this "installation" endpoint where they gather all this info separately about the current installation of the app on the device, including deviceToken etc. So you make a separate request to the `installations` endpoint to get all information.

Comment: Furthermore, if i see then Passbook Requests from the Apple Server to my Backend, they do not use a restful approach at all, but totally mix every information in a long request URL. So if I want to handle this, they expect a totally different structure somehow.

Comment: I can't really say for parse.com, but even though REST is fairly well defined, I do think that it has a little bit of personal preference in it as well. It could be that their backend made it nearly impossible to make it more efficient without doing a whole lot of code refactoring. It could also be that they just don't care about efficiency and that's how they made it because that's what came to mind when they were developing it.

Comment: And if Apple sends a specific type of request and you have no way of modifying it, you basically have to adapt your code to what they have, even if it means breaking specifications.

Comment: And that is, what frustrates me somehow at the moment, as I feel like hitting a wall with the whole topic. Somehow I feel, that devices should be a separate endpoint as there will be way more information included than just a device token, if I give the user the option to subscribe to channels for example. But then I always need two requests in the app.

Comment: I think I will go for your approach using `/users/12345/devices/` as it makes more sense to me than the parse approach.